# Is it possible to set Selectize options through input attribute?

Tags: jquery, html, selectize.js

How to set Selectize options through input attribute?

This doesn't work ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zELuw/9/)):

```
<input id="test" value="cat" options="cat,dog,snake" type="text"/>

<script>
    $('#test').selectize();
</script>
```

With the code above I want cat preselected, while dog and snake available as dropdown options. Cat in the `value` is fine, but others through `options` not. Any ideas? I'm missing something here.

Comment: Is this what you want http://jsfiddle.net/zELuw/10/?

Comment: No, I want three options, but as a default selection only one (in this example it is cat). I have updated problem description.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to do it manually.  Selectize isn't very clear about how to set its options, but [I figured it out](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/issues/745).

```
function to_selectize_options(items) {
    result = [];
    for (index in items) {
        item = items[index];
        result.push({
            text: item,
            value: item
        });
    }
    return result;
}

$('#test').each(function() {
    node = $(this)
    raw_options = node.attr('options')
    options = to_selectize_options(raw_options.split(','))
    node.selectize({options:options, delimiter: ','});    
})
```

[Check it out](http://jsfiddle.net/ev7m1b4e/2/).